# When I use a collection as a particle instance it show up but when I use a object instance I can see them

Tags: particles, collections

I have been following the donut tutorial and I am up to around 9:10 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZ5ungDgFNc). whenever I try to use a collection it just simply doesn't show in render or the viewport or anything. Please help.
[image]

Comment: your sprinkles collection is empty, select sprinkles objects and pull them to sprinkles collection

Comment: please provide blend file